# error[9582]: TypeError: Member "expectRevert" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in contract Vm

Tags: solidity, smart-contract-wallets, test

I'm having this error when i try to run the test `testCannotDecrementLargerNumbers`

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.13;

import "forge-std/Test.sol";
import "../src/Counter.sol";

contract CounterTest is Test {
    Counter public counter;

    function setUp() public {
        counter = new Counter();
        counter.setNumber(10);
    }

    function testIncrement() public {
        counter.increment();
        assertEq(counter.number(), 11);
    }

    function testSetNumber(uint256 x) public {
        counter.setNumber(x);
        assertEq(counter.number(), x);
    }

    function testDecrement(uint256 num) public {
        vm.assume(num < counter.getNumber());
        uint256 contractNum = counter.getNumber();
        counter.decrement(num);
        assertEq(contractNum - num, counter.getNumber());
    }

    function testFailDecrement(uint256 num) public {
        vm.assume(num > counter.getNumber());
        uint256 contractNum = counter.getNumber();
        counter.decrement(num);
        assertEq(contractNum - num, counter.getNumber());
    }

    function testCannotDecrementLargerNumbers(uint256 num) public {
        vm.assume(num > counter.getNumber());
        uint256 contractNum = counter.getNumber();
        vm.expectRevert(num > counter.getNumber());
        counter.decrement(num);
    }
}
```

Here is the Counter.sol file

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.13;

contract Counter {
    uint256 public number;

    function setNumber(uint256 newNumber) public {
        number = newNumber;
    }

    function getNumber() public view returns (uint256) {
        return number;
    }

    function increment() public {
        number++;
    }

    function decrement(uint256 num) public {
        number = number - num;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how you should use the vm.expectRevert().

Take a look here:

```
vm.expectRevert(abi.encodePacked("INVALID_AMOUNT"));
vault.send(user, 0);
```

Here on the first line, I'm letting the test file know that I expect the next call to revert with the revert message "INVALID_AMOUNT" (or the byte of it, but whatever).
THEN I call vault.send knowing it will fail, and therefore my test pass because the revert is was what I wanted.

So you test could look like this:

```
 function testCannotDecrementLargerNumbers(uint256 num) public {
        vm.assume(num > counter.getNumber());
        vm.expectRevert();
        counter.decrement(num);
    }
```

and they will pass since you are trying to subtract a number from a smaller number which will underflow, which will revert